# One div overlapping on another with screen size reduction

Tags: html, css

When the screen size is reduced from 800px to 574px the div 'image-container' overlaps with div 'form-container'. How to style div without making it overlap or it must come below first div (form-container) when it's about to overlap.

```css
.form-container {
    height: 90vh;
    background-size: cover;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: grid;
    background-image: url("images/water_droplet2.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 40% 10%;
  }

.image-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .image-container, .form-container {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-sm-4 form-container">
    <form getWeather="{this.getWeather}" fetchWeather="{this.fetchWeather}" />
    <ToastContainer transition="{Bounce}" className="toast-background" />
  </div>

  <div className="col-sm-8 image-container">
    {/* Weather Card */}
    <div className="background">
      <div className="container"></div>
    </div>
    {/* Weather Card Ends */}
  </div>
</div>
```

Any solution?
[image]
As you can see in the above image, The 'Weather Finder' part is form-container whereas the other part overlapping on it is image-container

Comment: Can you provide working code in fiddle and add over to your question

Comment: Yeah add working code

Comment: Yes I'll add please wait

Comment: What do you mean by below? Below as in z-axis or y-axis? If it's the y-axis, did you try setting the `.form-container` height in percentage?

Comment: @AkshitMehra Below means that when the image container is about to overlap it must come below the form-container.

Comment: Wait I will post image of it as well as fiddle working code

Answer (score 0):

use `z-indez` in the css file.

You could put the div that has to go below on `z-indez: -1;` and the other one on `z-indez: 1;` for example.